# Label and Data fields only holding 2 pieces of data from array

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

To preface: I'm very new to chart.js, so this it probably a lack of basic knowledge

I have 2 async functions: one to build the chart, and one to prepare the data.

This gets called after the window loads:

```
async function chartIt() {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    const globalVar = await getData();
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: globalVar.xlabels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Sign Ups',
            data: globalVar.ylabels,
            fill: false,
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
            borderWidth: 1
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {}
    });
  }
```

Second async function:

```
async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch('stats.csv');
    const data = await response.text();
    const xlabels = [];
    const ylabels = [];
    const rows = data.split(/\n/);
    rows.forEach(row => {
      const cols = row.split(',');
      rows.push(cols);
      console.log(cols);
      xlabels.push(cols[0])
      ylabels.push(cols[1])
    });

    console.log('xlabels: ' + xlabels);
    console.log('ylabels: ' + ylabels);
    console.log (rows)
    return { xlabels, ylabels };
};
```

The logs are coming back with some strange results, seen below:
[screenshot of console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saUty.png)

[Table in HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/867Xh.png)

Why are my labels and data being put in as a combination of 1 value from each array? Why is it stopping at only 1 of each?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Tried setting the numbers to be individual values instead of an array. Didn't show any results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this has anything to do with chartjs -- the code in your getData function seems very strange to me.

Specifically, this section:

```
rows.forEach(row => {
  const cols = row.split(',');
  rows.push(cols);
  console.log(cols);
  xlabels.push(cols[0])
  ylabels.push(cols[1])
});
```

I am not sure what format you're expecting the data to come out in, but you're adding more entries to your `rows` array inside a forEach function running on every element of `rows` -- this type of half-iterative, half-recursive behavior seems like a mistake, and is leading to two arrays with 1 label and 1 value each. It's hard to give more helpful advice than that without knowing how you've formatted the stats.csv file.

Chart.js expects, essentially, an array of labels and an array of values. What you are console logging currently is not that.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! The stats.csv file is just 2 rows of data

`SignUps,Check1,Check2,Check3,Check4,Check5,Check6
12,8,1,5,2,4,3`